# docker-compose service coverage report with pytest

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pytest, bamboo, pytest-cov

I'm a bit of a newbie, but I have an Atlassian Bamboo build that builds two services/containers with docker-compose, runs tests with pytest on the services, and in theory should fail the build if the coverage of the tests is under certain threshold.

I have docker-compose.yml file with the 2 services (service_1 and service_2) that have the following commands:

```
command:
  - "pytest"
  - "-slvk"
  - ""
  - "-m"
  - "marker_1"
  - "--cov=path/submodule"
  - "--cov-report"
  - "term-missing"
```

So the sequence of steps is as follows (simplified):

```
 1. docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml up service_1
 2. docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml up service_2
 3. docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml run --rm service_1 coverage report --fail-under 90
 4. docker-compose -f tests/docker-compose.yml run --rm service_2 coverage report --fail-under 90
```

The tests are executed according to the commands in the docker-compose.yml and I can see the report generated. So steps 1 and 2 are successfully executed.

The problem is that the coverage reports in steps 3 and 4 are generated for identical and created for the last created container, in this case service_2, but if i switch the places of steps 1 and 2, then the coverage would refer to service_1.